# Angular canvas MouseWheel: Scrolling vs. Zooming using button

Tags: angular, canvas, scroll, zooming, mousewheel

i am using angular 9 and trying to use the mouse wheel for two behaviors. There will be a toggle button in the screen (inside the canvas) with 2 options ( Scroll vs Zoom). In canvas, the default behavior will be zoom if we move the mouse wheel up or down.  Based on the toggle click, how i change this behavior so that instead of zoom, the scroll will fire and i will be able to load images one after the other (based on mouse wheel click).

```
@HostListener('wheel', ['$event']) onMouseWheel(event: any) {
    this.mouseWheel(event);
  }   

mouseWheel(event: any) {

    var event = window.event || event; 
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.wheelDelta || -event.detail)));
    if(delta > 0) {
       console.log(event);
    } else if(delta < 0) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    if(event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Somehow the 'mouseWheel()' method is not getting invoked when i move the mouse wheel up or down,instead 
he image gets zoomed in or out. Is it because I use canvas ? How can i change the behavior based on the toggle button click ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late but maybe this will be useful to someone.

I made a small example that I think does what you want. It creates a Canvas and draws a rectangle. With a switch one can then chose whether zooming into the canvas when scrolling or whether to move the rectangle up or down.

The html reads

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="picture">
    <canvas #picture width={{totalSize}} height={{totalSize}}></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="switchButton">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="zooming" (change)="zooming = !zooming">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I simply added a canvas of some size and a checkbox for the switch.
When now adding the .ts of the component

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scroll-canvas',
  templateUrl: './scroll-canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scroll-canvas.component.css']
})
export class ScrollCanvasComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    @ViewChild('picture', {static: false}) picture: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
    this.yOffset = 20;
    this.sideLength = 160;
    this.totalSize = 200;
  }

  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  viewInitialized = false;
  zooming = true;
  yOffset: number;
  sideLength: number;
  totalSize;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.viewInitialized = true;
    this.context = (this.picture.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
    this.draw();
  }

  @HostListener('wheel', ['$event']) onMouseWheel(event: WheelEvent) {
    if (this.zooming) {
      this.sideLength = this.sideLength - event.deltaY;
      this.draw();
    } else {
      this.yOffset = this.yOffset - event.deltaY;
      this.draw();
    }
  }

    private draw() {
    this.context.save();
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.totalSize, this.totalSize);
    this.context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,200,20)';
    this.context.fillRect(0, this.yOffset, this.sideLength, this.sideLength);
    this.context.restore();
  }
}
```

one gets the wanted functionality.
Here I simply draw a rectangle into the canvas. I also listen to scrolling events and based on the boolean set through the checkbox either change the size of the rectangle or move it up or down.

You can check-out the working code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fqpeba) where I added a component that does the job.

I hope this helps.